# git pull - fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

I did a "git checkout -b BranchName SHA1", where I used SHA1 of an old commit.
After that, I tried to do "git pull", but got the error:

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
        from /ruby/site_ruby/1.8/gitfarm/utilities.rb:337:in 'execute'
        from -:22:in 'run'
        from -:120
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Could someone please help me in understanding this issue and resolving this.

Thank you

Manu

Answer (score 0):

did u try git pull origin branch(master)

Also,
i have seen this type of error when i have issues with connectivity or authentication. ssh key not available for example.

Comment: Add more specifics to your question. What platform (windows/linux)are you using, both for client and server? Are you working with native git or jGit? Is this a new git server install? Are you using http-backend? From my experience, I've seen this occur when the permissions are incorrect for the service. Ex: execute permissions are not on the backend script for servicing git requests.

Comment: @JasonHuntley This is an answer, not a question